# How does Proxifier work?

Tags: delphi, proxy, transmission

As you know `Proxifier` is a program that allows network applications that do not support working through proxy servers to operate through an HTTPS or SOCKS.

It can handle any transmission from running applications. I want to know how it can do this and how I can write one like that.

Comment: You should rewrite the question if you really want go technical. And how this relates to [delphi]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FreeCap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng/?p=download) is your way to go.

It's released under GNU General Public Licence and written in Delphi.

Comment: I scrutinized the source code and found out that some units are effectively Windows 95 centric. Unless you need Windows 7 spoon-fed code, it's written well and for educational purpose it's a valuable starting point. Why not harness it with VMWare?

Comment: `Dll` file is the most important part of this project. It doesn't work on Windows 7 and I can't access its source. So, how actually can I use it?

Comment: Do you mean `inject.dll` and `proxy32.dll`?

Comment: Yes, inject.dll and proxy32.dll

Comment: Assuming you have downloaded `freecap_3.18-src.zip`, they are available respectfully in src\inject and in src\proxy32.

Answer (score 5):

A socksifier defines a dynamic library with the same functions as the OS socket layer, but defined in such a way as to use a socks proxy. The program being socksified uses that library instead of the OS-supplied one for its network communication.

Comment: Thank you, I need more information. I mean, technical info. How to write one like that by Delphi?