# How to implement ProxyCap / Proxifier?

Tags: sockets, proxy, linux-kernel, network-programming, sniffer

How them work in Mac OS X? What magic do they use?

If I want to implement like the two software, what technology I need to know?

I think the hardest thing to implement is forcing specific apps network connections through proxy servers.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? On Linux Redsocks/tsocks seem to use LD_PRELOAD, but on windows I could only find [WinDivert](https://www.reqrypt.org/windivert.html) which is not exactly the same and requires a driver to be installed. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9055888/1461004) suggests looking at FreeCap's source but that seems to primarily target windows 98 and not updated to use newer windows APIs.

Comment: @Bor691 Proxifier for macOS uses kernel extension.